# Lambda expression to get records that matches to list of data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have

```
string[] centersArr = new string[] {253, 6789, 9080};
```

I want to query database where center number start with any of the items of above centers array and the 8th character of center should be '1'.

```
var result = disctrict.Where(x => centersArr.Contains(x.Center) && x.Center[7] == '1').ToList();
```

My database has center numbers like 2533455, 2537890, 25312678, 678912 and so on..

Above query is returning null result. Please help me how to write this query.

Comment: ya sorry i corrected...i need 8th number character

Comment: What is the type of x.Center?

Comment: it is varchar in SQL

Answer (score 1):

i solved this:

```
.Where(x => centersArr.Any(c => x.Center.StartsWith(c)) && ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

`centersArr.Contains(x.Center)` is not going to work.

The items in `centersArr` genuinely cannot contain any of the example database values that you give.  And I suspect that's true for all of your database values.

In essence you are asking for a situation where the following is true (the following is super pseudo pseudocode)

```
ListOfCenters('A','B','C').Contains(ListOfLongerItemsFromDatabase('WORDA', 'BWORD', 'WORDC').
```

That's exactly backward.  WORDA or BWORD or WORDC can and do contain A,B, or C.  But not the reverse.

Does that help clarify?

This, however, should work:

```
var result = disctrict.Where(x => (x.Center.Contains("253") || x.Center.Contains("6789") || x.Center.Contains("9080")) && x.Center[7] == '1').ToList();
```

unless Linq to SQL cannot translate that into a SQL expression . . ..  If it doesn't work, at least it shows conceptually what you really want to be doing instead.

Comment: in database data always start with 'A' or 'B' or 'C'.

Comment: Yes but 253 does not contain 2533455.  2533455 contains 253.  But not the reverse.  Your code is trying to do the reverse.

Comment: See @bansi answer for a nice LINQ way of doing things.  I did the comparison1 || comparison2 || comparison3 just to be super explicit.  But bansi has a the nicest LINQ answer.

Comment: Oops missed that you were the original poster @bansi.  Glad you found a solution.  It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer.